# Finding Closed Form of a Recursive Sequence (Not involving summation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Given the following sequence $x_{1},x_{2}\ldots$
$$
\mbox{where}\quad x_{1} = 26\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
x_{n}=5n\,\, x_{n - 1} + 5^{n}\left(2n^{2} - 4\right) - 2n!
\qquad n \geq 2
$$
Find the closed form for $x_{n}$.

Any suggestions ?. I've completely blanked out on this one$\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

We have
$x_n
=5n*x_{n-1}+5^n*(2n^2-4)-2n!
$.

The $5$ and the $n$
suggest to me doing this:

Divide this by
$5^nn!$.
It becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x_n}{5^nn!}
&=\dfrac{5n*x_{n-1}}{5^nn!}+\dfrac{5^n*(2n^2-4)}{5^nn!}-\dfrac{2n!}{5^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{5^{n-1}(n-1)!}+\dfrac{(2n^2-4)}{n!}-\dfrac{2}{5^n}\\
\end{array}
$

Now,
let
$\dfrac{x_n}{5^nn!}
=y_n$.

This becomes
$y_n
=y_{n-1}+\dfrac{(2n^2-4)}{n!}-\dfrac{2}{5^n}\\
$.

You should be able to solve this
to get $y_n$
and then $x_n$.